# DNS resolves externally but not local to kube cluster (keys ARE located in etcd)

Tags: kubernetes

DNS can resolve to sites external to the cluster
etcd is modified correctly for new containers, services, nodes, etc

here are some details:

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl logs kube-dns-v10-q9mlb -c kube2sky --namespace=kube-system
I0118 17:42:24.639508 1 kube2sky.go:436] Etcd server found: http://127.0.0.1:4001
I0118 17:42:25.642366 1 kube2sky.go:503] Using https://10.254.0.1:443 for kubernetes master
I0118 17:42:25.642772 1 kube2sky.go:504] Using kubernetes API 
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$
```

Showing that etcd is being properly populated:

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl exec -t busybox -- nslookup kubelab.local
Server: 10.254.0.10
Address 1: 10.254.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubelab.local'

error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1

fedora@kubemaster ~]$ etcdctl ls --recursive
/kubelab.local
/kubelab.local/network
/kubelab.local/network/config
/kubelab.local/network/subnets
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.46.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.12.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.70.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.21.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.54.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.71.0-24
```

To help a little further:

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl exec --namespace=kube-system kube-dns-v10-6krfm -c skydns ps
PID   USER     COMMAND
    1 root     /skydns -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001 -addr=0.0.0.0:53 -ns-rotate=false -domain=kubelab.local.
   11 root     ps
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$
```

I DID change cluster.local to kubelab.local, but I also made the changes prior to my kubenodes:

```
KUBELET_ARGS="--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.kubeconfig --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --cluster-dns=10.254.0.10 --cluster-domain=kubelab.local"
```

/etc/resolv.conf appears to be ok on a testhost (in this case, busybox per DNS documentation example):

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl exec busybox -c busybox -i -t -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.kubelab.local svc.kubelab.local kubelab.local openstacklocal kubelab.com
nameserver 10.254.0.10
nameserver 192.168.1.70
options ndots:5
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$
```

Results = still a little frustrating:

```
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl exec -t busybox -- nslookup kubelab.local
 Server:    10.254.0.10
 Address 1: 10.254.0.10

 nslookup: can't resolve 'kubelab.local'
 error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
[fedora@kubemaster ~]$
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Having the same problem.

Comment: i did. in `kubernetes/contrib/ansible`, i overrode the `kube_master_api_port` flag in `group_vars/all.yml`...because of the way the project handled this variable. the result was that it wasn't carried over deeper into the kubernetes playbooks, so i had to make a manual override. in fact, I re-wrote this project for my own use here: https://github.com/v1k0d3n/fansikube

i'm still working on the fedora/contrail piece, but the rest is working just right. you just have to download the kubernetes binaries like in the unusable project (no different).

Comment: mine turned out to be another problem (or better a multitude of them) but now it all seems to stick together. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fedora@kubemaster ~]$ etcdctl ls --recursive
/kubelab.local
/kubelab.local/network
/kubelab.local/network/config
/kubelab.local/network/subnets
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.46.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.12.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.70.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.21.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.54.0-24
/kubelab.local/network/subnets/172.16.71.0-24`

This is showing flannel config, not skydns.

Comment: wow. major oversight in giving you that information. and here is the issue, although i can't quite understand where the deployment is getting messed up.

the definition file is: https://gist.github.com/v1k0d3n/edcb706072701311a61d

it looks to be in order, but no matter what command...it looks like the container is hosed: (sample is in same gist).

Comment: corrected etcd output on gist link above. the etcd keys are definitely there.

Comment: i have the exact same config. the one difference I see in the dns-addon.yaml is the key `initialDelaySeconds: 1` is not indented correctly.
Then, in your `kubelet` config, is the DNS address correct?

Comment: ah, I see a problem here: you still have `cluster.local` as your `domain` but your dns lookup show `kubelab.local`   Did you try to `nslookup kubernetes` simply to se if it resolve the local cluster? inside any other pod that is, not on the DNS pod.

Comment: crap, i'm really sorry...i actually redeployed and used cluster.local this time. i know...confusing, and i'm really sorry! exact same results though and i'm at a total end with this...can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: and kubelet config is: 
`KUBELET_ARGS="--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.kubeconfig --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --cluster-dns=10.254.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"`

in what's above is was the same (just changing for `domain=` flag. 


`[fedora@kubemaster ~]$ kubectl exec -it busybox -c busybox -- sh
/ # nslookup kubernetes
Server:    10.254.0.10
Address 1: 10.254.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes'
/ #`

Comment: Run: `kubectl --namespace=kube-system exec $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name | cut -f2 -d/) -c skydns -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost`

Answer (score 0):

you show the Replication controller info, but do you also have a Service setup?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "KubeDNS"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  clusterIP: 10.3.0.10
  ports:
  - name: dns
    port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  - name: dns-tcp
    port: 53
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: i added this on the gist. figured there was a little less to go wrong there. i'm using the ansible deployment from kubernetes/contrib.